# sml in list parameter functions recursive

Tags: sml, smlnj

list & an integer n. The function should add the n-th element of the list, and return the remaining list .for example

insertnth ([5,6,7],2,9);
output : [5,9,6,7]

n is the 2.
9 is which I add the second line

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, lutzlover. You need to go read a text book or some introduction to SML. For example see the [SML/NJ Literature](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/literature.html) page.

Basically you have two ways of solving this problem. Given a function `insertnth(xs, pos, n)`, then the ugly non-functional way is to split the list at position `pos`, and then return `left @ n :: right` where `left` and `right` are the left and right part of the split. Or the more functional way, with a recursive function that goes through the list `xs` element by element, decrementing the `pos` variable each time, and then when you reach position 1, then return `n` appended to the remaining list, to stop the recursion.

Comment: I had that. fun insertnth (h::t,1 ) = t|
insertnth (h::t,n) = h :: insertnth ( t, n-1 ) ;    Is it like that ?

Comment: Well you will need atleast three parameters, just as you did in your original question and as i did: `insertnth(xs, pos, n)`. Besides that your almost there